# Not able to access nexus3 OSS on port 8081 installed on Amazon Ec2 RHEL

Tags: amazon-ec2, service, nexus3

I have installed Nexus3 OSS on AWS Ec2 using the below link.

http://www.cidevops.com/2017/09/how-to-setup-sonatype-nexus-on-redhat.html

But not able to open with http://public_ip:8081

I have installed httpd too using yum install.

Not sure what am missing here.

Also I have provided http and ssh access while creating instance.

Comment: Are you able to ssh into the instance?

Comment: Yes ssh is perfectly working.

Comment: what happens if you curl http://localhost:8081 from the machine?